# Kinect for windows: status change event can't be triggered

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

I add a event handler to the `StatusChanged` event, but the handler never executed:

My WPF file `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
 public MainWindow()
 {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.Loaded += this.MainWindow_Loaded;
      //...
 }

 protected void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
      KinectSensor.KinectSensors.StatusChanged += KinectSensors_StatusChanged;
      //...
 }
 void KinectSensors_StatusChanged(object sender, StatusChangedEventArgs e)
 {               
        switch (e.Status)
        {
            case KinectStatus.Connected:
                MessageBox.Show("CONNECTED");
                break;
            case KinectStatus.Disconnected:
                MessageBox.Show("DISCONNECTED");
                break;
            case KinectStatus.Initializing:
                MessageBox.Show("INITIALIZING");
                break;
            case KinectStatus.Error:
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
                break;
        }
        //...
    }
```

I can run Kinect with this program, no matter what I do to the Kinect, the status changed can't be triggered.What should I do?

Comment: What exactly have you tried? It pays to be specific. It might be something wrong with your test methodology rather than the code.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that KinectSensor.KinectSensors.StatusChanged returns a new object each time you call it rather than returning a global object, or it returns an object which it only caches internally with a weak reference.

If it does either of these things, then the KinectSensorCollection instance is not rooted by your code, and may get collected before the event gets chance to fire. Try storing the reference to the KinectSensorCollection instance in a member variable of your MainWindow and see if the event fires.